# Арендовать сервер 1 х ядро 2.8 ГГц

Tags: django, ubuntu

Всем здравствуйте, я бэк разработчик, вот знакомлюсь c миром vds, есть вопрос у меня бэк на джанго еще есть celery и телеграм бот, нашел сервер vds за небольшие деньги, характеристика следующая 1 х ядро 2.8 ГГц, 2гб RAM, потянит ли  этот сервер веб приложение?

Comment: Потянет. Другой вопрос, что за приложение и на какое коилчество аудитории рассчитан. С такой железкой на многое рассчитывать не стоит...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar не большой интернет магазин, ну представим 100 чел в день

Comment: Ну в принципе попробовать захостить можно, в теории выдержит

Comment: @VladimirGonchar , вопрос если будет два ядра, джанго автоматический распределится на обоих или все равно будет крутится на одном?

Comment: Это зависит не от джанго, а от того, как вы будете его запускать. Любой адекватный WSGI/ASGI сервер (uwsgi, gunicorn, uvicorn) имеет опции для настройки количества запускаемых процессов/потоков. Сколько запустите, столько ядер и займёт